# what is the internal about java devide in jvm source code

Tags: jvm

in java code , there is one line about int k = j/3;

the one byte code of j/3 is IDIV

what is the IDIV in jvm source code level?

it need to be some c/c++ code or asm code.

how can i find it in jvm source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed mapping from Java byte codes to machine code. It depends on the target platform and is not static. To begin with the byte codes are executed as they are (I would say interpreted, but some people don't like that word). Then they are transformed into machine code by the JIT after a while, but again the actual mapping can and will vary.

Comment: special thanks for your review :)  the orginal request of my question is, i am interesting about the performance of i/8 and i>>3 just on linux, from the result the performance almost same. i guess in asm code the i/8 maybe optimized to asm code sar? but i am not sure... i need visit the jvm c or asm code to verify my guess is right or wrong...

Comment: @yaoweijq replacing `i/8` with `i>>3` is one of the most trivial tricks, the JVM can do for sure, as long as the necessary prerequisites are fulfilled. E.g., it only works this way if the number is positive, so the JVM may generate code just using this replacement, when it can prove that the number is always positive, or insert code handling negative numbers, or just not use the trick, depending on surrounding conditions. But depending on surrounding conditions, it also may remove the entire operation, if its result is not really needed.

Comment: @Holger i also try the similiar code with g++, the compiler directy optimize the asm code with i/8 to sar , so i have the similar guess on java/jvm.

Comment: The Java compiler never optimizes nowadays. The optimize flag has been removed. That is intentional (though it may change again). The idea is that the JIT (just in time compiler) does the optimizations at run time instead. So, as I wrote you really don't know what assembly code you will get. To begin with you won't get assembly code at all and when the JIT has had a chance to compile and optimize the code the result will depend on many things and can vary between runs for the same program on the same machine.

Comment: @ewramner thanks a lot. It seems very complex for this issue:) . And i don not know why there is vote down for it. Now i think i am standing outside the gate of jvm/jit house.

Comment: It may not only “vary between runs for the same program on the same machine”, even within a single run, a JVM may compile the same code multiple times, to adapt to changing conditions or to utilize gathered additional information.